# iOS image view change tint color when did alert sheet dismiss

Tags: ios, swift, uialertsheet

I have a stack view, I tapped photo select item and I show alert sheet, and when alert sheet dismissed and my image view's image did change to imageView's tint color.
Code:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "newsfeed_camera.picker".localized, style: .default, handler: {
        action in
        self.present(self.imageManager.cameraPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
    let photoAction = UIAlertAction(title: "newsfeed_photo.picker".localized, style: .default, handler: {
        action in
        self.present(self.imageManager.photoPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "newsfeed_button.cancel".localized, style: .cancel, handler: {
        action in
        self.postTV.becomeFirstResponder()
    })

    alertController.addAction(cameraAction)
    alertController.addAction(photoAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I show with image like this,

[image: First state]

[image: Second State]

[image: Final state]

Comment: I think you have to add selected image as well for uibutton.

Comment: @aBilal17 I will try it

Comment: if you are using button than you can use button.setImage(image, for: .normal)

Comment: @RahulGUsai it's not working

Comment: @aBilal17 it's not working

Comment: then you should use .selected instead of .normal

Comment: @RahulGUsai yes I use with .normal state

Comment: @HalilİbrahimYILMAZ could you please share your code written within dismiss block/closure? you need to implement logic for the selected state and cancel state in completion or dismiss closure/block.

Comment: @HarendraTiwari I added code.

Comment: Have you tried without action sheet?

Comment: @Mannopson I tried with alert controller but continue same issue

Comment: @HalilİbrahimYILMAZ Can you provide some information about your button. It’s programmatically implemented?

Comment: @Mannopson I use storyboard, and this views in stack view.